# String.Format hinting in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin-studio, string.format

Having worked with Xamarin Studio, I have come to love the `String.Format` hinting and highlighting features:

[image: Xamarin hint and highlight]

In Visual Studio, by default, there is no such a feature:

[image: Visual Studio without hinting and highlighting]

I have given a shot at some queries over the Visual Studio Gallery and Google, but haven't come up with anything. Maybe anyone here has a clue whether such extension exists and where could I find it?

Am not sure whether this question obliges by the rule:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

I hope it does, if not, well, I'll delete it and look elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JetBrains' ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper) offers exactly this functionality:

[image: ReSharper's string.Format helper]

Sometimes I wonder what ReSharper can NOT do... :-)

Comment: Somehow I had this feeling, but did not fully believe... Damn, ReSharper looks like a must.

Comment: Looks like it is not available anymore this feature, I have ReSharper Ultimate 2018.2